# $\forall a[P(a)\implies Q(a)]\wedge \forall a[Q(a)\implies P(a)]\stackrel{?}{\equiv} \forall a[[P(a)\implies Q(a)]\wedge [Q(a)\implies P(a)]]$

Tags: logic

I'm reading: Devlin's *Joy of Sets*.

He gives the definition of the axiom of extensionality:

> [image]

The definition of subset:

> [image]

And then there is this exercise:

> [image]

Rewriting it, I'd have:

\begin{eqnarray*}
  {(x=y)}& \iff &{(x\subseteq y)\wedge (y\subseteq x)} \\ 
  {}&\iff &{\forall a[a\in x\implies a\in y] \wedge \forall a[a\in y\implies a\in x]}
\end{eqnarray*}

Are the following two expressions equivalent:

$$\forall a[a\in x\implies a\in y] \wedge \forall a[a\in y\implies a\in x] \\ \stackrel{?}{\equiv}\\ \forall a([a\in x\implies a\in y] \wedge [a\in y\implies a\in x])$$

Intuitively, I guess they are. But I'm not sure.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6410/distribution-of-universal-quantifiers) answer.